# web crawling pages with JS events

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler

I am trying to get a list of singles released in 2018 from allmusic.com.

It is easy enough to go to their advanced search page and input those parameters, but then I would have to copy and paste the information by hand. All the information is in the html, but it has be generated by clicking the search button and the page navigation buttons. The url itself doesn't change. That puts it well out of my ability to crawl via my limited beautiful soup skills.

Does anyone know how to web crawl java script generated html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking into the details of the particular website, I imagine you would need to find out what HTTP requests the JS code is making and work backwards from there.
Start by inspecting the network calls (e.g. in Chrome DevTools, just look in the Network tab) and then write something to make those same calls to retrieve the data.